# How to fix an error when creating Sharepoint Variations?

Tags: exception, sharepoint

I'm getting some crazy errors when trying to create variations in Sharepoint. Has anybody seen this error?

```
PublishingPage::AttemptPairUpWithPage() Ends. this: http://wseasp05/PT/Paginas/Destaque1.aspx, destPageUrl: /ES/Paginas/Destaque1.aspx   
Begin DeploymentWrapper::SynchronizePeerPages(), sourcePage = Paginas/Destaque1.aspx     
DeploymentWrapper::SynchronizePeerPages(), synchronizeDestUrl = /ES/Paginas/Destaque1.aspx
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP\11c7c12e-030d-4860-a942-f5ab71f0930d\ExportSettings.xml' is denied.     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)     at System.IO.FileInfo.Create()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.Ex...  
...portDataFileManager.Initialize()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.InitializeExport()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.Run()     
Export Completed.    
DeploymentWrapper.SynchronizePeerPages() catches UnauthorizedAccessException.  Spawn failed for /ES/Paginas/Destaque1.aspx   
End of DeploymentWrapper.SynchronizePeerPages()
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

```
'C:\Windows\TEMP\11c7c12e-030d-4860-a942-f5ab71f0930d\ExportSettings.xml' is denied.
```

- Please, verify that user that is
  logged in SharePoint has access to
  that file (particularry that temp
  folder)
- If code is running as timer job,
  verify that the user that is running
  timer service has those permissions.
- Maybe you just need to run the code
  in context of application pool
  account? Use
  [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)
  then (and verify that application
  pool account can access that file)

Or maybe it's issue accessing
   `/ES/Paginas/Destaque1.aspx`. Either
   way, verify that user's have
   appropriate permissions.